# relation between the affine connection, the connection coefficients, and the Christoffel symbols

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I was reading about the role of the affine connection in General Relativity and i am confused on 1 aspect. From what i have understood,
The connection coefficients $\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu} $ are the coefficients of the connection operator $\nabla$ in a local frame and they  determine $\nabla$ so that in many books $\nabla$  and $\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu} $ are often used interchangeably (i guess?am i right?). my question is: does the connection coefficients takes the name of CHristoffel symbols only when the connection is the Levi-Civita connection or they are the same thing for every connection one could define?

Comment: I would call the connection coefficients Christoffel symbols for any connection.

Comment: @Deane i thought the same but wikipedia says otherwise https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols#Christoffel_symbols_of_the_second_kind_(symmetric_definition)

Comment: I think you’ll find that there is no uniform standard for this.

Comment: Usually, the "Christoffel Symbols" are defined with respect to a symmetric tensor field or refers to a symmetric connection. Riemannian geometry is an example of this important special case. It just means that the torsion tensor $S_{h\,\,k}^{\,\,l}=\Gamma_{h\,\,k}^{\,\,l}-\Gamma_{k\,\,h}^{\,\,l}\equiv 0$. But in general $\Gamma_{h\,\,k}^{\,\,l}\neq\Gamma_{k\,\,h}^{\,\,l}$ and the connection coefficients are just the coefficients of the affine connection.